# Cluster dendogram: does the x-axis has a ordinal/cardinal meaning, or just aesthetic?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

It is usual to represent the output of a hierarchical clustering algorithm through a dendogram, which shows in the x-axis the units to be clustered, and on the y axis the cluster dissimilarity measure for each cluster/step.

What is the meaning of this x-axis? Does it have an ordinal meaning, like going further away on the axis means units are further apart? This is clearly the case if we took distances over a single variable, in which case the x-axis represents indeed the ordering of units. But I don't think this is correct in general... so: **what can we infer from the x-axis in term of ordering of the units in the metric chosen**? For example, assuming labels on the x-axis are going from A to Z:

- Can we infer that if A a B and next to each other, at least one of them is a nearest neighbor to the other?
- Or does this holds only if A and B are next to each other, and they are part of the same initial cluster?

Thanks!!

And just for the sake of having a cute picture, here is a dendogram with R:

```r
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>